# mq_open giving "too many open files"

Tags: c, posix, message-queue, systems-programming, ipcs

I created a message queue with following code. First few times it works properly.

```
int main()
{
    mqd_t mqdes;
    char mq_name[10] = "/mq";
    int oflag = O_CREAT | O_RDWR, ret;
    struct mq_attr attr;

    attr.mq_maxmsg = 1024;
    attr.mq_msgsize = 2048; 

    mqdes = mq_open(mq_name, oflag, 0766, &attr);
    if(mqdes == -1) {
            perror("mq_open");
            if(errno == EMFILE)
                    perror("EMFILE");
            exit(1);
    }

    printf("mqueue created, mq_descriptor: %d\n", mqdes);

    ret = mq_close(mqdes);
    if(ret == -1) {
            perror("mq_close");
            exit(2);
    }
    printf(" mq closed successful\n");


    return 0;
}
```

After that, it's giving following error

```
mq_open: Too many open files
EMFILE: Too many open files
```

But why i'm getting this error? How can I see possix message queues like `ipcs` is for system V?

Comment: Are you getting the `mq closed successful\n` message at the end of the session?  [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3056992/645128) is another example of using mq_open, maybe you can see something there that you are not doing.

Comment: @ryyker: how can it goes to end of the program? mq_open fails and giving error.

Comment: Regarding your question _How can I see possix message queues like ipcs is for system V?_  [THIS](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/93230-what-posix-equivalent-ipcs-m.html) link talks a little about it.  I do not see anything else in what you posted that would suggest that you should have too many files open.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the resource limits:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct rlimit rlim;
memset(&rlim, 0, sizeof(rlim));
rlim.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
rlim.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;

setrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, &rlim);
```

Comment: Worked for me thanks, but not sure why increasing limit from ulimit command did not helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while trying something. If you have by accident too many open message queues left on your system, you can try deleting your mqueue's in directory `/dev/mqueue`. This worked for me.

Also you might want to use `mq_unlink(const char *name)` after the `mq_close()` to ensure that the queue is removed from the system as described [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_unlink.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by increasing `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` via [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit).

If the hard limit (rlim_max) is too low as well (which was the case for me), you will have to give your process the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` privilege so that you can set the hard limit before you set the process limit (rlim_cur). Either run `$ setcap 'CAP_SYS_RESOURCE=+ep' /path/to/executable` over an executable or edit `/etc/security/capability.conf` to give CAP_SYS_RESOURCE to a user/group.