# communication between processes - fork and msgget C

Tags: c, ipc

I'm trying to implement the communication between processes, I studied the ipc and fork, for now, I managed to generate the children with the fork it works without problems.
But I need to make the children communicate with each other. I read something, but I could not understand how the messages work. would anyone be kind enough to give me an example with msgget?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html

Comment: If it's ok to use POSIX version, then look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056307/how-do-i-use-mqueue-in-a-c-program-on-a-linux-based-system